# Mongodb Aggregation : Project an array without the first element

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e3179e83708dc0dcfefaf"),

    "CaseNumber" : "T978045628",

    "ServiceReferences" : [ 

        ObjectId("5e317d48bc13eaf17712a786"),

        ObjectId("5e317f0ec08d57f4a88c3444"),

        ObjectId("5e317f0ec08d57f4a88c3234")

    ]

}
```

I have a collection with above fields. I want to project the  'ServiceReferences' array except first element as I want to skip first indexed element of the array. Please help me. I have tried a couple of use cases like :

```
db.getCollection('cases').aggregate([{
             "$project": {

                  "ServRefs": { $pop: { ServiceReferences: -1 } }
              }
       },
       {
        $lookup: {

            from: 'services',

            localField: 'ServRefs',

            foreignField: '_id',

            as: 'serviceDoc'

        }
    }, { $unwind: '$serviceDoc' }])
```

Comment: Can you please give an example of the expected result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just try with this one

```
db.getCollection('cases').aggregate([
{ $project: { ServiceReferences: 1, SerRef: { $slice: [ "$ServiceReferences", 1, {$subtract: [ {$size:"$ServiceReferences"}, 1 ]} ] }} }
])
```

Comment: Thank you. It is working fine...  First I checked the existence of the length then it worked :: { "$match": {  "ServicesReferences.1":{$exists:true}} }, Otherwise it will through :: errmsg" : "Third argument to $slice must be positive: 0

Comment: Good. It's better to check the existence.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the first element of an array by using `$pop`

> The $pop operator removes the first or last element of an array. Pass $pop a value of -1 to remove the first element of an array and 1 to remove the last element in an array.

You can apply it to your projection.

Here is the documentaiton:
[$pop documentation mongoDb](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pop/#up._S_pop)

Comment: I cann't remove first element from array because I need it in the next projection which is in the same aggregate query. I just want to ignore the first element.

Comment: I want to Project all items in an array except first one, to new field which is exact opposite of this query ::   {
            "$project": {
                "ServRef" : { "$arrayElemAt" : ["$ServicesReferences", 0] }
            }
        }

Answer (score 0):

use slice

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/

The following syntax returns elements from the specified position in the array:

db.in_house_beta.aggregate([

```
 { $project: { "experience_combined": { $slice: [ "$experience_combined", 1 ] } } },
 { $unwind: "$experience_combined" },
 { $unwind: "$experience_combined.Company" },
 { $group:{ _id:{ Company:'$experience_combined.Company'}, count: { $sum:1} }
```

}])